How do I put <Select> in a combobox when the DISTINCT is used
I am trying to put <Select> in a combobox while using the DISTINCT is use.
It works without the DISTINCT keyword:
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(zGV.csAviation))
{
    try
    {
        string query = "select '<Select>' as name, 0 as id union Select name, id from Airlines ORDER BY Name ";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "airline");

        cbxAirline.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbxAirline.ValueMember = "ID";

        cbxAirline.DataSource = ds.Tables["airline"].DefaultView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write exception info to log or anything else
        MessageBox.Show("Error occurred in Airline!");
    }
}


Why are you trying to use DISTINCT? UNION gives you distinct results anyway.

What is the error you receive?

You could simply apply the "non-ui" data that you are ultimately after.
string query = "
        select '<Select>' as name, 0 as id 
        union 
        Select name, id from Airlines ORDER BY Name ";


No need, Union will make stuff distinct anyway

Not sure I follow " will make stuff distinct". The first query will put the UI stuff and after that there is nothing distinct in the following queries.

The point being that union (as opposed to union all) already guarantees uniqueness over the whole result set so adding that DISTINCT there doesn't do anything

Doh! You are correct, sir.

@siggemannen - Updated answer.
